# How to speed up download using Java I/O

Tags: java, io, download

I'm quite new to using Java I/O as I haven't ever before and have written this to download a .mp4 file from www.kissanime.com.

The download is very, very slow at the moment (approximately 70-100kb/s) and was wondering how I could speed it up. I don't really understand the byte buffering so any help with that would be appreciated. That may be my problem, I'm not sure.

Here's my code:

```
protected static boolean downloadFile(URL source, File dest) {
    try {
        URLConnection urlConn = source.openConnection();
        urlConn.setConnectTimeout(1000);
        urlConn.setReadTimeout(5000);

        InputStream in = urlConn.getInputStream();

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(out);

        int fileSize = urlConn.getContentLength();

        byte[] b = new byte[65536];
        int bytesDownloaded = 0, len;

        while ((len = in.read(b)) != -1 && bytesDownloaded < fileSize) {
            bout.write(b, 0, len);
            bytesDownloaded += len;

         //  System.out.println((double) bytesDownloaded / 1000000.0 + "mb/" + (double) fileSize / 1000000.0 + "mb");
        }

        bout.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Thanks. Any further information will be provided upon request.

I can't find any questions on here related to downloading media files, and I'm sorry if this is deemed to be a duplicate.

Comment: Yuo could try a bigger buffer, but really the only thing that would slow this code down is printing the progress. You don't need to keep track of the bytes downloaded so far against the total length. You will get EOS when the download completes. In any case you should test the total so far before the read, not after it.

Comment: I've tried a bigger buffer and it has no effect really. I tried new byte[65536] and that didn't help at all. Let me try it without the sout and report back. Removing the System.out.println() and it didn't effect the speed of the download. It downloads the first 2mb really quickly and then slows down.

Comment: Yeah, you should probably try and remove the println(), printing each iteration is quite expensive...

Comment: Read my last comment Arash :)

Comment: I wonder: is there really a problem to solve? If you download the file through some other means, does it download faster then? It might be the site itself that is capping the download speed.

Comment: Right clicking and save-as from the site and saving it as a .mp4 works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it was the vast number of redirects from the link that caused the download speed to be throttled. Thanks everyone who answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try using  [IOUtils.toByteArray](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toByteArray%28java.io.InputStream%29), It takes an inputstream and returns an array with all bytes, in my opinion it's generally a good idea to check the common utility packages like apache-commons and guava and see if what you're trying to do hasn't already been done

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the file from InputStream then use this bellow method of apache-commons 
[FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyToFile%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.File%29) ()

```
public static void copyInputStreamToFile(InputStream source,
                     File destination)
                              throws IOException
```

*Copies bytes from an InputStream source to a file destination. The directories up to destination will be created if they don't already exist. destination will be overwritten if it already exists. The source stream is closed.*

Always use file and IO related stuff by using library if available.There are also some other utility methods available & you can explore .

[IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toByteArray%28java.io.InputStream%29)

[FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyToFile%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.File%29)